# In Bash: How do I expand a (possibly) relative path versus a specified base?

Tags: bash

In Python it's easy to textually join two directories while respecting absolute paths:

```
os.path.join('/base', 'rel_subdir')
  '/base/rel_subdir'
os.path.join('/base/', 'subdir')
  '/base/subdir'
os.path.join('/base', '/absolute')
  '/absolute'
```

How do I get the same behavior in bash? Especially if the directories may or may not really exist?

My best answer so far, but I'm hoping for a oneliner.

```
function _joinrel {
    local base="$1"
    local rel="$2"

    if [[ "${rel}" == /* ]] ; then
        echo "${rel}"
    else
        echo "${base%/}/${rel}"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the solution (one liner!):

```
[[ "${REL:0:1}" == / || "${REL:0:2}" == ~[/a-z] ]] && echo "$REL" || echo "${BASE}/${REL}"
```

This check if relative path start with / and also with ~ (home) that is some kind of absolute path

Comment: I somehow missed this reply, sorry for the slow acceptance. I think that will work, but it is quite the oneliner. ;>